# SVG drawn offscreen is clipped on iPhone UIWebview

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, svg, mobile-safari

I am currently developing an iPhone application using PhoneGap. Inside this application I use SVG images a lot.

I load up these SVG images inside HTML <object> tags in order to pass parameters and allow scripts to execute (scripts do not execute when the SVG is loaded in an image tag).

When the SVG image is loaded on screen, everything works fine, however when it is rendered offscreen (as in the case of our "pager" control), it gets clipped, and only any portion of it that was visible when it was loaded gets drawn.

1. Has anyone else had this problem? How did you fix it?
2. Does anyone have any ideas on how to force the object tag to redraw regularly (If I change to img tags it draws correctly, but then no parameters or scripts are available.)